# Can you define custom plugins for karma-runner

Tags: karma-runner

Karma (aka testacular) seems to have a plugin system - lots of projects in the github page are actual plugins to define adapters, preprocessors, etc...

I'm desperately trying to find a way to register a new plugin, but I have no clue if this is feasible or not. Anywone ever managed to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not super familiar with writing plugins, but have installed a few (although I still might be doing it wrong).

Assuming you've `npm install -g karma@canary` and done similar for your plugin.

Say your plugin has a `"name": "karma-mycoolplug"` in your package.json file (see [karma-chrome-launcher's package.json](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/blob/master/package.json)). You'd then add that name to the plugins section of your karma.conf.js, i.e.

```
// plugins to load
plugins = [
  'karma-qunit',
  'karma-chrome-launcher',
  'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
  'karma-mycoolplug',
  'karma-junit-reporter'
];
```

Maybe you're looking for deeper info than that?

Comment: Actually, my issue was simply that I was not using the right version of karma (custom plugins are only supported after version 0.9.0). Thanks anyway !